# In presto i keep getting java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1

Tags: high-availability, cloudera-cdh, presto

I am using presto 0.136 and a setup of 10 nodes but inspite of putting the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml in proper hive.properties file, i keep getting the error below. Appreciate if someone can help. This is not a duplicate issue as all similar problems do not have this stack trace..

```
2016-08-05T09:17:29.893Z    WARN    http-client-shared-scheduler    com.facebook.presto.memory.RemoteNodeMemory Error fetching memory info from http://10.195.0.44:8090/v1/memory: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout 2000ms
2016-08-05T09:17:39.900Z    WARN    http-client-shared-scheduler    com.facebook.presto.memory.RemoteNodeMemory Error fetching memory info from http://10.195.0.63:8090/v1/memory: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout 2000ms
2016-08-05T09:18:13.924Z    WARN    http-client-shared-scheduler    com.facebook.presto.memory.RemoteNodeMemory Error fetching memory info from http://10.195.0.62:8090/v1/memory: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout 2000ms
2016-08-05T09:18:51.534Z    ERROR   remote-task-callback-0  com.facebook.presto.execution.StageStateMachine Stage 20160805_091848_00000_z7g3h.1 failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.createFileSystem(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.getInternal(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.get(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:384)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.createParquetRecordReader(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:364)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.<init>(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:203)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetRecordCursorProvider.createHiveRecordCursor(ParquetRecordCursorProvider.java:102)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.getHiveRecordCursor(HivePageSourceProvider.java:128)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.createPageSource(HivePageSourceProvider.java:106)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.java:43)
    at com.facebook.presto.transaction.LegacyConnectorPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(LegacyConnectorPageSourceProvider.java:40)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSourceManager.createPageSource(PageSourceManager.java:48)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.createSourceIfNecessary(TableScanOperator.java:268)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.isFinished(TableScanOperator.java:210)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:377)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:303)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:580)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(TaskExecutor.java:505)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$Runner.run(TaskExecutor.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
    ... 30 more


2016-08-05T09:18:51.535Z    ERROR   query-execution-2   com.facebook.presto.execution.QueryStateMachine Query 20160805_091848_00000_z7g3h failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.createFileSystem(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.getInternal(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.get(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:384)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.createParquetRecordReader(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:364)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.<init>(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:203)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetRecordCursorProvider.createHiveRecordCursor(ParquetRecordCursorProvider.java:102)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.getHiveRecordCursor(HivePageSourceProvider.java:128)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.createPageSource(HivePageSourceProvider.java:106)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.java:43)
    at com.facebook.presto.transaction.LegacyConnectorPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(LegacyConnectorPageSourceProvider.java:40)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSourceManager.createPageSource(PageSourceManager.java:48)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.createSourceIfNecessary(TableScanOperator.java:268)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.isFinished(TableScanOperator.java:210)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:377)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:303)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:580)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(TaskExecutor.java:505)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$Runner.run(TaskExecutor.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add the core-site and hdfs-site configurations to etc/catalog/hive.properties like shown below -

hive.config.resources=/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml,/""/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

where "" is the location to your hadoop binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HA, then try disabling it. This should work. Note: when I had tried this in past when using presto:0.123, HA support was not available. I dont know what is the status now.